# Run a job once at the given time in time zone

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduler, schedule

My code is to schedule a task at specific time to run

```py
from datetime import date
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

# Start the scheduler
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

# Define the function that is to be executed
def my_job(text):
    print(text)

# The job will be executed on May 31, 2021
exec_date = date(2021, 5, 31)

job = sched.add_date_job(my_job, exec_date, ['text'])
```

So the above code will run on that date. My requirement is to specify all date, time and time-zone at which the function has to run at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [crontab](https://linuxize.com/post/scheduling-cron-jobs-with-crontab/)  or if you want to do within python and not interfere with linux use of [schedule](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-schedule-library/) library.